# How to convert openweather unix timestamp to correct Date

Tags: date, datetime, utc, unix-timestamp, openweathermap

I've seen so many posts telling that you simply need to multiply the timestamp to 1000 but the problem is I always get less minutes than expected.

**Here's my code:**

```
const getCity = async () => //fetch city logic
const city = await getCity();
const time = new Date(city.dt * 1000);
console.log(time.getMinutes());
```

Current time: 11:**58**

Epxected output: 58

Actual ouutput: 47

**Here's an example of JSON response:**

```
{
  ....
  "dt": 1560350645, <-- Time of data calculation, unix, UTC
  "timezone": -25200,
  ...
 }
```

Comment: 1560350645 corresponds to Wednesday 12. June 2019 14:44:05 UTC. So pretty far from the current time.

Comment: Which is your programming language? JavaScript? Just guessing. Are you expecting 58 from 1560350645? Could you give one concrete and precise example of `dt` from JSON, full expected output (date and time) and full actual output? That should make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: It's 17:54 in my city and so I expect to get 54 minutes from `1619275921`, which I've got from the response. However, the output is 52 minutes. I didn't update the data I stored from the response, so here's data after update.

Comment: 1619275921, that’s Saturday 24. April 2021 14:52:01 UTC alright. So it seems there’s a delay of a couple of minutes before you get the data. You may want to check with an online (or offline) conversion too such as [Epoch & Unix Timestamp Conversion Tools](https://www.epochconverter.com/).

Comment: There's definitely something not right with my fetch data, because I tried to access the same city in a few minutes and the timestamp was always the same. And it's been updated only a minute ago. Or the question is how often the timestamp gets updated in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well...as it turned out, the timestamp updates once in a while in the database. And at the same time, I was too naive to think it was in real time :D So there was no problem from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

// you will need the timestamp and timezone value to be able to convert!

```
import moment from "moment";

function convUnixTamestampAndTimezoneToDateHour (unixtimestamp, timezone) {
        let date = moment.utc(unixtimestamp,'X').add(timezone,'seconds').format();
        return date; //Format de retorno: 2022-07-19T20:00:52
}
```